# How to use Joda-Time to set default paraameters in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jodatime

I have a Jasper report that uses the following to set the default query dates:

```
<parameter name="FROM_DATE" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new org.joda.time.DateTime().minus(org.joda.time.Period.years(2)).toDate()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="TO_DATE" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new org.joda.time.DateTime().toDate()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Regardless of how many years I subtract, the report always seems to run for the year prior to today's date.  I guess there are two questions arising here - why it always seems to default to a year and how to configure it to default to the specified number of years?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have just changed the order of the parameters in the xml - placing the date parameters at the top.  This seems to have resolved the issue, but I am not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters should be put at the top of Jasper before Fields, Dataset, and Query. Because you will use the paramater in details or somewhere else, it need to be declare first at the top.

Comment: Than you - much appreciated